# Opening dialog activity on creating another activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I've got an activity, call it A, that when initially opened I would like to programmatically open a another dialog theme activity, B, over the top.  The user would select some info from the dialog activity and return to activity A.  When resuming to activity A at some later point the data set would be available, so the dialog would not need to be shown.

The problem is attempting to start the dialog activity from activity A's onResume or onCreate methods causes strange and undesirable behaviour.  The task appears to kind of freezes for a good few seconds and then the dialog is displayed correctly, but activity A isn't shown behind.

Thanks
Peter

Comment: Can you post code snippets? It may show why the Dialog gets loaded but not the Activity

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem (I think). My project is open source and you can see the problem if you build the application from http://github.com/bryanjswift/simplenote-android/tree/login-dialog

Answer (score 0):

check this:

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/CustomDialogActivity.html

i think u should create activity as a dialog.then it helps

u can set style and theme for ur activity by this..